# Join tables based on tokenized columns

Tags: oracle

INSTALL

```
INSTALL     ICP_NMI         METER
40306953    73145959056     A5573461-000ýB0200444-000
40420671    73147449692     A7568936-000ýA0495957-000
```

MRSM_INDEX

```
SEQNO   MRSM_NMI    METERSERIAL
2016    7314595905  A5573461
1634    7314744969  A7568936
```

I have two tables, where I need to perform a join based on values from columns that need to be tokenized. I need to join the two tables where the ICP_NMI  column (minus the last digit) is equal to the MRSM_NMI column, and then tokenize the METER column based on ‘ý’ and remove the last four digits from each meter, and then filter the results where first tokenized METER does not match the METERSERIAL in the MRSM_INDEX table. How would I implement this in SQL?

Comment: Please post the expected output as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUBSTR(ICP_NMI,1,LENGTH(ICP_NMI)-1) removes the trailing character, thus the first join condition can be:

```
SUBSTR(ICP_NMI,1,LENGTH(ICP_NMI)-1) = MRSM_NMI
```

To find the position of ý you can do INSTR(METER,'ý'), and thus the characters before it and stripping off 4 digits is SUBSTR(METER,1,INSTR(METER,'ý')-5), giving a second join condition of

```
SUBSTR(METER,1,INSTR(METER,'ý')-5) = METERSERIAL
```

Comment: Is there a way of joining this on the condition of that the METER column does not contain the METERSERIAL column?

Comment: Would this not just be "!=" instead of "=" ?